# Alter request object before validation

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
if($key == "postcode") {
    $this->validate($request, [
    'postcode' => ['required','regex:#^(GIR ?0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9ABEHMNPRV-Y])?)|[0-9][A-HJKPS-UW]) ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$#'],
    ]);
}
```

I need to convert the postcode field into uppercase **before** I pass it in to this validate function. I tried `$request->input('postcode') = strtoupper($request->input('postcode'));` but got;

> Can't use method return value in write context.

I want to keep `$request` as the whole `Request` object ideally. Otherwise I’d just pass in the `$request->input('postcode')` on it's own. Actually I think the method is type-hinted for `Request`.

This is Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with the [`merge`](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) method:

```
$request->merge(array('postcode' => strtoupper($request->input('postcode'))));
```

Maybe it is also interesting to know that you can make your validation case-insensitive, by adding the `i` modifier at the end of the regular expression:

```
#^(GIR .... $#i
```